# Find common keys in at least two dicts

Tags: python

I'd like to obtain a dict of the following form (not strict):

```
{65: ['Fresh', 'Frozen'],
 66: ['Fresh', 'Delicatessen'],
 75: ['Grocery', 'Detergents_Paper'],
 128: ['Fresh', 'Delicatessen'],
 154: ['Milk', 'Grocery', 'Delicatessen']}
```

when I have an input which is list of dicts. Their keys may be intersected and values - not. For example in our case we have the same key `65` in two dicts with value `Fresh` and `Frozen`.

This is my solution and I'd like to improve it:

```
outliers = [
    {65: 'Fresh', 66: 'Fresh', 81: 'Fresh', 95: 'Fresh', 96: 'Fresh',
     128: 'Fresh', 171: 'Fresh', 193: 'Fresh', 218: 'Fresh', 304: 'Fresh',
     305: 'Fresh', 338: 'Fresh', 353: 'Fresh', 355: 'Fresh', 357: 'Fresh',
     412: 'Fresh'},

    {86: 'Milk', 98: 'Milk', 154: 'Milk', 356: 'Milk'},

    {75: 'Grocery', 154: 'Grocery'},

    {38: 'Frozen', 57: 'Frozen', 65: 'Frozen', 145: 'Frozen', 175: 'Frozen',

     264: 'Frozen', 325: 'Frozen', 420: 'Frozen', 429: 'Frozen', 439: 'Frozen'},

    {75: 'Detergents_Paper', 161: 'Detergents_Paper'},

    {66: 'Delicatessen', 109: 'Delicatessen', 128: 'Delicatessen',
     137: 'Delicatessen', 142: 'Delicatessen', 154: 'Delicatessen',
     183: 'Delicatessen', 184: 'Delicatessen', 187: 'Delicatessen',
     203: 'Delicatessen', 233: 'Delicatessen', 285: 'Delicatessen',
     289: 'Delicatessen', 343: 'Delicatessen'}
]

common_outliers = {}
for outlier in outliers:
    for idx, feature in outlier.items():
        if idx not in common_outliers:
            common_outliers[idx] = [feature]
        else:
            common_outliers[idx].append(feature)
common_outliers = {idx: features for idx, features in common_outliers.items()
                   if len(features) > 1}
print(common_outliers)
```

Comment: I think I misread it before, are you trying to filter out all entries that have only one feature in the list?

Comment: @TomKarzes I'd like to show only those items which occurred more than 1 time.

Comment: use a `defaultdict` or the `.setdefault` method of a normal `dict`

Comment: Ok then looks fine to me.

Comment: This kind of question seems better suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: FYI, the `defaultdict` suggestion people have made lets you skip the check to see if a key has been seen before.  It can be used to automatically create a new, empty list when a missing key is accessed.  The run time should be comparable to what you have.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga It is clear how to do it with collections.deafultdict, but I can't fihure out how to do this with dict.default(dict):
```
    for idx, feature in outlier.items():
        common_outliers.setdefault(idx, [])
        common_outliers[idx].append(feature)
```

Comment: You just do `d.setdefault(k, []).append(v)`

Comment: @Thanassis I think the question name `Find common keys in at least two dicts` more suitable here. Of course I might not add the solution, but it is, I assume, helpfull. Please clarify

Comment: @ArtemZhukov, you are already giving the solution to the problem of finding common keys in multiple dicts. What you are asking is how to make your solution better. This kind of questions are perfect for codereview.SE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from itertools import chain
from collections import defaultdict

d_dict = defaultdict(list)
for k, v in chain.from_iterable([ i.items() for i in outliers ]):
    d_dict[k].append(v)

dict(filter( lambda x:len(x[1])>1, d_dict.items() ))
```

Output:

```
{65: ['Fresh', 'Frozen'],
 66: ['Fresh', 'Delicatessen'],
 75: ['Grocery', 'Detergents_Paper'],
 128: ['Fresh', 'Delicatessen'],
 154: ['Milk', 'Grocery', 'Delicatessen']}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to make it easier, it allows to get rid of the key checking step:

```
from collections import defaultdict

common_outliers = defaultdict(list)
for outlier in outliers:
    for idx, feature in outlier.items():
        common_outliers[idx].append(feature)

common_outliers = {idx: features for idx, features in common_outliers.items()
                    if len(features) > 1}
```